# regex replace '...' at the end of the string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like:

```
text1 = 'python...is...fun...'
```

I want to replace the multiple '.'s to one '.' only when they are at the end of the string, i want the output to be:

```
python...is...fun.
```

So when there is only one '.' at the end of the string, then it won't be replaced

```
text2 = 'python...is...fun.'
```

and the output is just the same as text2

My regex is like this:

```
text = re.sub(r'(.*)\.{2,}$', r'\1.', text)
```

which i want to match any string then {2 to n} of '.' at the end of the string, but the output is:

```
python...is...fun..
```

any ideas how to do this?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making it a bit complex, you can easily do it by using regex as `\.+$` and replace the regex pattern with single `.` character.

```
>>> text1 = 'python...is...fun...'
>>> new_text = re.sub(r"\.+$", ".", text1)
>>> 'python...is...fun.'
```

You may extend this regex further to handle the cases with input such as `...` only, etc but the main concept was that there is no need to counting the number of `.`, as you have done in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for the string ending with three periods, and replace them with a single one.

```
import re
x = "foo...bar...quux..."
print(re.sub('\.{2,}$', '.', x))
// foo...bar...quux.
```

Comment: This will only replace exactly three .'s.

Comment: Updated to replace 2 or more .'s with a single one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\.{2,}$', '.', 'I...love...python...'))
```

As simple as that. Note that you need to escape the `.` because otherwise, it means whichever char
except `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the multiple '.'s to one '.' only when they are at
>   the end of the string

For such simple case it's easier to substitute without importing `re` module, checking the value of the last 3 characters:

```
text1 = 'python...is...fun...'
text1 = text1[:-2] if text1[-3:] == '...' else text1

print(text1)
```

The output:

```
python...is...fun.
```