# Regex to fix (all the matches or none) at the end to one

Tags: python, regex, ruby, substitution, regex-greedy

I'm trying to **fix the `.` at the end to only one** in a string. For example,

```
line = "python...is...fun..."
```

I have the regex `\.*$` in Ruby, which is to be replaced by a single `.`, as in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/BVlPJI/4), which don't seem to work as expected. I've searched for similar posts, and the closest I'd got is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242532/10078895) in Python, which suggests the following,

```
>>> text1 = 'python...is...fun...'
>>> new_text = re.sub(r"\.+$", ".", text1)
>>> 'python...is...fun.'
```

But, it fails if I've no `.` at the end. So, I've tried like `\b\.*$`, as [seen here](https://regex101.com/r/BVlPJI/3), but this fails on the 3rd test which has some `?`'s at end.

My question is, why `\.*$` not matches all the `.`'s (despite of being greedy) and how to do the problem correctly?

---

Expected output:

```
python...is...fun.
python...is...fun.
python...is...fun??.
```

Comment: What’s the expected / correct result for the three example strings?

Comment: @Stefan - added the expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use an alternation matching either 2 or more dots or assert that what is directly to the left is not one of for example `!` `?` or a dot itself.

In the replacement use a single dot.

```
(?:\.{2,}|(?<!\.))$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `\.{2,}` Match 2 or more dots
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<!\.)` Get the position where directly to the left is not a `.` (which you can extend with other characters as desired)
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string (Or use `\Z` if there can be no newline following)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUW9Qc/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0zQk3f)

For example

```
import re 
strings = [
    "python...is...fun...",
    "python...is...fun",
    "python...is...fun??"
]

for s in strings:
    new_text = re.sub(r"(?:\.{2,}|(?<!\.))$", ".", s)
    print(new_text)
```

Output

```
python...is...fun.
python...is...fun.
python...is...fun??.
```

---

If an empty string should not be replaced by a dot, you can use a positive lookbehind.

```
(?:\.{2,}|(?<=[^\s.]))$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fx1tvW/1)

Comment: It doesn't matter what the trailing token is, if the dot is absent. _Edit_ -  I've edited the __third link__ correctly.

Comment: @vrintle Like this `(?:\.{2,}|(?<=[^\s.]))$`https://regex101.com/r/3vidlj/1

Comment: Yes, exactly. That seems to fit the problem :)

Comment: `([^.])$|\.+$` might be shorter (with `\1.` as sub), as the input doesn't have any trailing spaces.

Comment: @vrintle Then you could make it `([^.])$|\.{2,}$` as a single dot will already be ok so there does not have to be a replacement.

Comment: I still have a doubt in _why_ `\.*$` _not matches all the_ `.`'s _(despite of being greedy)_, can you explain this to me?

Comment: @vrintle I see that you mean, when I test it in python 2 it works. https://ideone.com/WMwE09 Perhaps it changed in python3 with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: @vrintle I tested it in 3.6 https://rextester.com/EUMMI94158 and that works. When I [test it in 3.7](https://tio.run/##dY1BCsJADEX3OUUILlop2bgTpAdRKQhTnYUzQ5Kinn4aB102i0/gv88rH3vkdKg1PksWQwmgJjHdFU94BvSj0hhmjuoxL9@Xho1usxhHgivAnAUVY8Kf5tjwFF6Thbe5VALrcuuELrzf0YDkLtS@YcUn1v3hHmpdAQ) it stops working

Comment: @vrintle I think this is the reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642571/retrieving-python-3-6-handling-of-re-sub-with-zero-length-matches-in-python-3